# Can't figure out layout dependencies in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-constraintlayout

I need to create a layout which should look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. The `TextView` content should be wrapped so the `ImageView` is always at the ent of the text.
2. `TextView` should not overlap with other views regardless of content.
3. `ImageView` can have visibility `GONE` during runtime, so `TextView` should use the space of `ImageView`.

My current layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pref_list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Long long"
        android:textSize="@dimen/preference_text_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pref_list_item_help_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pref_list_item_title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_help_primary_color"
        android:contentDescription="@string/help" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/pref_list_item_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`ConstraintLayout` is an option, but I couldn't create constraints that satisfy my needs.

Comment: Use `ConstraintLayout` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ConstraintLayout` you can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pref_list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Long long asdasd asd asd aasdadasd"
        android:textSize="@dimen/preference_text_size"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/pref_list_item_help_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pref_list_item_help_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/pref_list_item_title"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_help_primary_color"
        android:contentDescription="@string/help"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/pref_list_item_switch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/pref_list_item_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/pref_list_item_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `TextView` and the `ImageView` are chained together with `packed` style and horizontal bias of `0` to keep them aligned to the left. The `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` has to be set for the `TextView` to prevent it from overlapping other `Views` in case the text gets too long. All this also works well when you want to toggle `ImageView's` visibility.

Comment: Great Work!! :)

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Is there a way to set app:layout_constrainedWidth in `Design` view?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that there isn't.